# How to make styles defined in a nested class apply to a slotted component in Stencil.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, stenciljs

I have a Navbar component, but now I have to break it up into smaller parts, which need to be slotted inside.

This is how the navbar looks like:
[image: Navbar]

Now, I have made the left-side menu items into a separate component, which I need to now nest using a slot.

**Big problem**: I have close to 700 lines of SCSS code containing numerous amount of nested classes. The Navbar has a responsive design for 5 screen-size resolutions.

The menu item itself is inside another wrapper, which is inside another one, and the classes look like this:
[image: menu-item class]

The relevant Navbar JSX structure looks like this:
[image: navbar jsx]

Now, this class `navbar__container-left-content-navigation-item` is the class that needs to be applied to the new `navbar-menu-item component`, which is slotted. The component looks like this:
[image: menu-item component]

The problem is that, I don't know how to do that!

I can't just copy/paste this style into a new stylesheet and link it to the `navbar-menu-item` component, because the class is nested inside multiple other classes of elements that exist on the navbar component.

I also cannot link the `navbar-menu-item component` to the `navbar.scss` stylesheet, because since the component is slotted, the styles would not apply to the element.

Even if I do this:
`& ::slotted([slot=left-menu-item]) { .. }`
.. the styles will apply to the slot wrapper, and not the element that's inside.

Can somebody please tell me what am I suppose to do now? How do I make the classes apply to the slotted components?

My HTML structure looks like this:
[image: navbar html structure]

Comment: I absolutely don't understand what you are asking; but you are aware slotted content is styled in its lightDOM, not in shadowDOM. Slotted (I prefer "reflected") content is a like a mirror image; ``:slotted`` is like painting on the mirror glass; you can't style its contents; that is done in lightDOM

Answer (score 0):

The `::slotted` selector will only allow you to apply style to the outer (host) element of a slotted component - it will not style anything inside it that is shadow DOM. Only a component's own style sheet is able to style its shadow DOM content.

If you really need to use your top-down style approach, then disable shadow DOM in the components that need to be styled this way.

If you are using shadow DOM and are trying to "pass down" style cues from parent to child components whether the children are slotted or not, you need to take a different approach. You could use a component property, but in your case you might want to use style class names.

So, simplifying for the sake of an example, suppose you do this:

```
<menu>
    <menu-item slot="left-menu-item" class="navbar__container-left-content-navigation-item"></menu-item>
</menu>
```

In `menu-item.scss` you can then do this:

```
:host(.navbar__container-left-content-navigation-item) {
    ...
}
```